Why are dynamic arrays called ArrayLists in Java?
The point of Java's ArrayLists is that they adjust their length automatically whenever items are inserted or deleted. If I understand it correctly, ArrayLists are wrappers around primitive arrays.
I was taught that:

arrays are data structures that offer random access in O(1) but can do insertion and deletion only in O(n), while
lists offer insertion and deletion in O(1) but provide random access only in O(n),

meaning that a data structure can't be an array and a list at the same time.
Why then does Java call it “ArrayList” – isn't that an oxymoron? (Wouldn't “DynamicArray” be more appropriate?) Or do ArrayLists actually have a “lists trope”?

Your definition of List is specifically for a linked list. Anyway you can ask on langdev stack exchange for the reasons why langiages are designed the way they are.

I didn't know that “list” isn't a synonym for “linked list”, thanks!

Yes, "list" is an abstract data type that doesn't refer to one implementation specifically unless in certain contexts. Python lists are dynamic arrays, while Lisp specifically uses linked lists. I agree it should've been called DynamicArray, but naming is inconsistent across languages (similar spirit question https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/why-did-c-standard-library-name-the-containers-map-and-unordered-map-instead-o)

Peanuts are neither a pea, nor a nut.  What's up with that?
My point is that naming isn't required to follow whatever rule you are imagining.  An ArrayList is not an array, and not a list.  It has some aspects in common with an array, and some aspects with a list, but it is not identical with either.  That is fine.  It is still a fine name.
